# Detecting SMS incoming and outgoing

Tags: android, sms

I'd like to detect sms incoming and outgoing automatically from my application at background whenever this app is opening or not. how to code?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-sms-mms-in-android

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is a good tutorial on both sending and receiving sms messages: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android .

For the incoming messages you can indeed configure a broadcastlistener for detection. *

Detecting outgoing messages is also possible (just altered this post since I dind't know this). from: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg26420.html

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
  contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://
sms"),true, myObserver);
```

Comment: Hey can you post your complete solution?

Comment: Beginning with API level 19, the URI is added to the API and you get use  `Telephony.Sms.CONTENT_URI` instead of `Uri.parse("content://
sms")`.

Comment: @soclose can you post solution please?

Comment: If we register with content://sms than its called even on Message is deleted. How do I specifically detect if its SENT msg only. Also in my device content change for content://sms/sent is not triggered.

Answer (score 1):

System broadcasts appropriate messages when messages are sent and received. You will have to create BroadCastReceiver for appropriate Intents(see documentation for details ... I think it is `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` for interception not sure of sending though)