# How to know when the phone receives a message

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting SMS incoming and outgoing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735571/detecting-sms-incoming-and-outgoing)

I want to write a app that run silently. The app needs to be notified about new messages. It just needs to to know when a new message is received, doesn't need to read the content of the message.

How can I achieve this?

Update: Is there a function which checks if there are any new messages at a given time. My idea is to then put this check in a loop, and check for new messages regularily.

Comment: Check this other SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735571/detecting-sms-incoming-and-outgoing

Comment: You should have googled "Android Receive SMS"

Comment: don't loop it, it will slow down your application and waste processing. Try implementing some event listener to actively notify when there is an oncoming sms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good tutorial on both sending and receiving sms messages: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android .

For the incoming messages you can indeed configure a broadcastlistener for detection. *

Detecting outgoing messages is also possible: http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg26420.html

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
  contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://
sms"),true, myObserver);
```

Answer (score 1):

To see incoming messages you need BroadcastReceiver and persmissions: RECEIVE_SMS.
here is easy tut:
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android