# how to read incoming sms

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting SMS incoming and outgoing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735571/detecting-sms-incoming-and-outgoing)

i want to read an incoming sms to check perticular value exist in sms

i found this sms reciving code
i want to check  if reciving sms have following value  xml values

plz help me how i check

```
//this is response which i check in reciving sms

00
LOG
00
Adeel Aslam
10.00
10/05/2012 10:00
+100


//this is code which i found for sms recive
     public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
  {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    //---get the SMS message passed in---
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();        
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
    String str = "";            
    if (bundle != null)
    {
        //---retrieve the SMS message received---
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";        
        }
        //---display the new SMS message---
        Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }   

}
```

Comment: but i want check if sms have particular value not just read  how i check ?

Comment: What's the difference? You read a message to check the data contained therein.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `contains()` method to check if specific word is present in the sms or not.

```
 if(str.contains("LOG"))
  {
    // Perform your task here.
   }
```

Comment: str.contains("LOG")    so in this code  Log is a specific word?

Comment: `LOG` is value which you want to check in your incoming sms.You can put it anything.

Comment: how to start new acitivtty if particular sms recive?

Comment: Simply use `switch case` if it satisfies the condition/case then start the respective activity. :)

Comment: i sed this 

 if(str.contains("00"));
                {
                 Intent k = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), AgAppMenu.class);
                 startActivity(k);
                }
              

but is show error

Comment: Have you included your activity in `AndroidManifest` file under the `application` tag.And what error you are having?

Comment: what the error you are having in logcat?