# Is it possible to know when user send SMS?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to get intent in my application when user sends SMS from other (may be default) app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can use something called as a ContentObserver. See this thread for details:

[Detecting SMS incoming and outgoing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2735571/detecting-sms-incoming-and-outgoing)